# Unable to delete the Node from Firebase Database?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

When I try to delete a node from Firebase Database, nothing happens.

I tried to log the ID's of the respective nodes which are going to be deleted, and found that they are different than the Original ID to be deleted.

This is what I've tried :

```
likesReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(firebaseAuth.getUid());


 final String id = likesReference.push().getKey();

    holder.fav.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {


            if (sharedPreferences.contains(Title)) {

                Log.e("ID FOR DELETION IS ", id);
                likesReference.child("Liked Posts").child(id).removeValue();
                holder.fav.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.unfavorited);
                sharedPreferences.edit().remove(Title).apply();
                Toast.makeText(context, "Removed from Favorites !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {

                holder.fav.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.favorited);
                sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("FavNews", MODE_PRIVATE);
                myEditor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                myEditor.putString(Title, Title);
                myEditor.apply();

                Toast.makeText(context, "Added to Bookmarks", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                likesReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {


                        HomeModel homeModel1 = new HomeModel(holder.newsTitleTextView.getText().toString().trim(), holder.newsDetailTextView.getText().toString().trim(),
                                holder.timesAgo.getText().toString().trim(), homeModel.getNewsImage(), homeModel.viewCounts);


                        Log.e("KEY IS", id);  //right one

                        likesReference.child("Liked Posts").child(id).setValue(homeModel1);


                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });


            }
```

This is the ID's that i logged in logcat :

```
E/KEY IS: -M9-xEcTQOlBIY47qkIp
```

and

```
 E/ID FOR DELETION IS: -M9-xIKhGufcZ1-yg8qb
```

Why is the node not deleted?

Comment: It is happening because you are pushing (creating) a new key every time you call `push()`.

Comment: so, what should I write ?